# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})}{n}}{e^{-n\lambda(1-e^{-\frac{2}{n}})}-e^{-2n\lambda(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}})}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have the sequence $$\frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})}{n}}{e^{-n\lambda(1-e^{-\frac{2}{n}})}-e^{-2n\lambda(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}})}}$$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, and I need to evaluate it as $n \to \infty$.

Wolfram Mathematica says the limit should be $e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})\frac{e^{2\lambda}}{\lambda}$ but I can't seem to calculate it.

Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @mjw I think L'Hôpital's rule makes the expression more complicated, not less...

Comment: @Math1000, you are right!

Comment: Let $p=1/n$, then apply L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p=1/n$.

$$S=\frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})}{n}}{e^{-n\lambda(1-e^{-\frac{2}{n}})}-e^{-2n\lambda(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}})}} = \frac{{e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})}{p}}{e^{-\frac{\lambda}{p}(1-e^{-2p})}-e^{-\frac{2}{p}\lambda(1-e^{-p})}}$$

Now take the limit as $p\rightarrow 0$ and use  L'Hopital's rule:

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{p\rightarrow 0} S&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})}{e^{-\frac{(1-e^{-2p})\lambda}{p}} \left(\frac{\lambda}{p^2}(1-e^{-2p})-\frac{2e^{-2p}\lambda}{p}\right)-e^{-\frac{2(1-e^{-p})\lambda}{p}} \left(\frac{2\lambda}{p^2}(1-e^{-p})-\frac{2e^{-p}\lambda}{p}\right)}\\&=\frac{e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})}{e^{-2\lambda}\lambda}\\&=\frac{e^\lambda-1}{\lambda}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you! With your tip and using notable limits I was able to prove it!

Comment: That's great!  You are welcome!